# How to use PromptDialog.Confirm() in MessageController.cs Post Method

Tags: c#, azure, bots

I want to prompt Question with Yes No options in chat window,

```
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
    {
        ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
        Activity reply;

        if (activity != null)
        {
            // check if activity is of type message
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                await GetEntityFromLUIS(activity);
            }
            else if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
            {
                    constructResponse = "Hi";
                    reply = activity.CreateReply($"{constructResponse}");
                    await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply); //After this we need Prompt question with Yes r No
            }
        }
        else
        {
            connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }

        return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }
}
```

How to prompt question with ** Have Questions ** and **Yes** **No** after display **Hi**. Next to below code

```
reply = activity.CreateReply($"{constructResponse}");
await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use PromptDialog.Confirm like that

```
PromptDialog.Confirm(context, Confirmed,"Have question");
```

Confirmed() happen after the answer by the user

```
public async Task Confirmed(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> argument)
    {
        bool isCorrect = await argument;
        if (isCorrect)
        { }
        else
        { }
    }
```

Comment: Where I need to declare this Confirmed function, In MessageController.cs or need to create any other class. I did declare in Same MessageController.cs but bot is not responding eventhough it is not displaying "Hi".